# how to return as array in php function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, intervention

im using laravel 5.4 and intervention plugin to upload images as ajax

i will upload images in php controller and it will return a response (file name).

and the returned variables from php is an array but in javascript it going to string and i cant iterate that

```
 public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $array = $request->file('image');
    $count = count($array);

    for ($i=0 ; $i<$count; $i++)
    {
        $img = Image::make($request->file('image')[$i]);
        $img->widen(800);
        $img->fit(800,600);
        $rnd = rand(10,10000);
        $location = 'images/carimages/c'.$rnd.'.jpg';
        $img->save($location);
        $answer[] = $rnd;
    }
    return $answer;
}
```

Comment: Instead return the array as an JSON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass php array to javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305636/pass-php-array-to-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function upload(Request $request) {
    $answer=array();
    $array = $request->file('image');
    $count = count($array);
    $answer=array();
    for ($i=0 ; $i<$count; $i++)
    {
        $img = Image::make($request->file('image')[$i]);
        $img->widen(800);
        $img->fit(800,600);
        $rnd = rand(10,10000);
        $location = 'images/carimages/c'.$rnd.'.jpg';
        $img->save($location);
        $answer[$i] = $rnd;
    }
//here print $answer and check 
//you can also check $answer with function var_dump(); 
    echo json_encode($answer);
    die;
}
```

Decode this array like

```
json_decode($json_array,true);
```

Comment: its still string in js . from php its array ir json correctly but when i get this with xhr.responseText in js it going to string

Comment: i solved it from js code.
it should to convert to json from javascript :

var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
console.log(obj[1]);

tnx

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
return response()->json($answer);
```

Comment: Please add your string result in question

Answer (score 0):

Try using `json_encode()`.

This will solve your issue.

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $answer=array();
    $array = $request->file('image');
    $count = count($array);

    for ($i=0 ; $i<$count; $i++)
    {
        $img = Image::make($request->file('image')[$i]);
        $img->widen(800);
        $img->fit(800,600);
        $rnd = rand(10,10000);
        $location = 'images/carimages/c'.$rnd.'.jpg';
        $img->save($location);
        $answer[] = $rnd;
    }
    echo json_encode($answer);
    die;
}
```

Comment: `echo json_encode(array("answer"=>$answer)); die;` and also write `dataType:'json'` in ajax code so it will get as json in ajax success response